# Count occurrences of value in a map

Tags: java, hashmap, counting

I have a map of the following type:

```
private HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> entireMap;
```

The keys go from 1 - n. The subMap inside the entireMap is of the following type:

```
HashMap<String, Object> subMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
```

Every key of the entire map contains this subMap (and a lot more):

```
subMap.put("user_name", usid[1]);
```

So i have something like this at the end:

```
{1 {"user_name" = "Arthur", "otherKeys = ..."}}
{2 {"user_name" = "Bela", "otherKeys = ..."}}
{3 {"user_name" = "Ceasar", "otherKeys = ..."}}
{4 {"user_name" = "Ceasar", "otherKeys = ..."}}
{5 {"user_name" = "Bela", "otherKeys = ..."}}
{6 {"user_name" = "Bela", "otherKeys = ..."}}
```

Now I want to count the max occurence of a user_name in the entireMap, in this case it would be 3 (bela occures three times).

How can I do that?

Comment: But in subMap, you cannot have duplicate keys..

Comment: Sorry, i just noticed each record of your example is @ entireMap level.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an example of an implementation.

**Note**: don't use such map initialization in production code!

```
    HashMap<Integer, HashMap<String, Object>> entireMap = new HashMap<>();
    entireMap.put(1, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Arthur");
        put("other_key1", "val");
        put("other_key2", "val");
    }});
    entireMap.put(2, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Bela");
        put("other_key2", "val");
    }});
    entireMap.put(3, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Ceasar");
    }});
    entireMap.put(4, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Ceasar");
    }});
    entireMap.put(5, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Bela");
    }});
    entireMap.put(6, new HashMap<String, Object>() {{
        put("user_name", "Bela");
    }});

    Map<Object, Long> result = entireMap
            .values()
            .stream()
            .map(map -> map.get("user_name"))
            .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    System.out.println(result);

    Long max = Collections.max(result.values());
    System.out.println(max);
```

Output:

```
{Ceasar=2, Arthur=1, Bela=3}
3
```

Comment: Or without the `map()` call: `Map<Object,Long> counts = 
        entireMap.values()
             .stream()
             .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(v -> v.get("user_name"),
                      Collectors.counting()));`

Comment: @Eran yes, of course. But I prefer to separate responsibilities for each operation

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to go for java 8 feature than you can do it by simple iterating through the map.

```
Map<String, Integer> resultMap = new HashMap<String, Integer>();

for (int key : entireMap.keySet()) {
    String userName = (String) entireMap.get(key).get("user_name");

    if (resultMap.containsKey(userName)) {
        resultMap.put(userName, resultMap.get(userName) + 1);
    } else {
        resultMap.put(userName, 1);
    }
}

System.out.println(resultMap);
```

**Output :**

{Arthur=1, Ceasar=2, Bela=3}

Comment: `resultMap.get(userName) + 1` will throw a NullPointerException.  You probably would want to do `resultMap.getOrDefault(userName, 0)`.  Or, prior to Java 8, something like `Integer count = resultMap.get(userName); resultMap.put(count != null ? count.intValue() + 1 : 1);`.

Comment: @VGR Doesn't his `resultMap.containsKey(userName)` condition prevent that from happening?

Comment: @phatfingers Yes, it does.  I don’t know why I didn’t see that.

Comment: @VGR : If you have down voted me and if you think my answer is correct, than can you please revert your vote? It will help me to build my reputation.

Comment: The system will not permit me to change my vote unless you edit your question in some way.  I suggest changing the first line to `Map<String, Integer> resultMap`, as variable types should reference a contract (Map) rather than an implementation (HashMap).

Comment: (Strictly, this answers just the hard part of *How can I **count** the **max** occurrence?*)

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way to do it using Java 8 features, but without streams:

```
Map<String, Long> counts = new HashMap<>();
entireMap.forEach((k, v) ->
    counts.merge(v.get("user_name"), 1L, Long::sum));
```

In the `counts` map you'll have the count for each user. Then you can find the entry with the max value:

```
Entry<String, Long> max = Collections.max(
    counts.entrySet(),
    Map.Entry.comparingByValue());
```

Answer (score 0):

In Java 7 or lower you can use [Guava MultiSet](https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2012/12/google-guava-multisets.html):

```
List<Object> names = new ArrayList<>();
for (HashMap<String, Object> outerMap : entireMap.values()) {
    names.add(outerMap.get("user_name"));
}

HashMultiset<Object> objects = HashMultiset.create(names);

objects.forEachEntry((name, count) -> System.out.println(name + " -> " + count));
```

As a result:

```
Ceasar -> 2
Arthur -> 1
Bela -> 3
```

Comment: (Strictly, this answers just the hard part of *How can I **count** the **max** occurrence?*)