# Get key count or occurrences in List<Map<String, String> : Java

Tags: java, collections

I have List<Map<String, String>> that have family member details. Depending on added family member the rest details will be processed.
There can be other family member like uncle, aunt, niece... etc. These records can be single or multiple.

```
  | Add_Family_Member | Full_Name     | Date_Of_Birth | Gender |
  | Sibling           | Sibling name  | 12-12-1990    | Male   |
  | Sibling           | Sibling name2 | 12-12-1990    | Male   |
  | Sibling           | Sibling name2 | 12-12-1990    | Male   |
  | Child             | Child name    | 12-12-2010    | Male   |
  | Child             | Child name2   | 12-12-2000    | Female |
  | Spouse            | Spouse name   | 12-12-1990    | Male   |
```

So how can I count Add_Family_Member i.e. Sibling count 3, Child count 2 and spouse count 1.

Comment: So you basically need group by?

Comment: how are you going to fit that record into a hashmap?

Comment: Please, share your **attempt** and specify the problem you've encountered. Every question on StackOverflow is expected to demonstrate an effort. See [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [Why is "Can someone help me?" not an actual question?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/284236/why-is-can-someone-help-me-not-an-actual-question)

Comment: I dont know why you use List<Map<String,String>> when you could use a custom class/Record to represent each record instead.

Comment: Try looking at [Count occurrences of value in a map](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44500446/count-occurrences-of-value-in-a-map?adlt=strict&toWww=1&redig=C18AF74D8EC54E0FB8B6FAF4A71EDBDD).

Answer (score 0):

**Using Java 8 stream**

*You can try using stream `groupingBy` feature to get the `count` of each member type shown as below:*

**Logic:**

Here, I have created a POJO class `FamilyMember` with some attributes as given in the problem statement and created a list of FamilyMember and then by using `stream` operation and using `groupingBy`, grouped the data by `memberType` and using `Collectors.counting` getting the count of each memberType.

**Suggestions:**

As mentioned in the problem statement, the given input is in the form of `List<Map<String, String>>` so instead of Map you can use a POJO class to hold the data for each member as shown in my implementation.
And moreover, how you are holding this kind of structure in the form of `Map<String,String>`

**Code:**

```
    public class Test {

       public static void main(String[] args) {

        FamilyMember member1 = new FamilyMember("Sibling","Sibling name",
                LocalDate.of(1990,12,12),"Male");
        FamilyMember member2 = new FamilyMember("Sibling","Sibling name2",
                LocalDate.of(1990,12,12),"Male");
        FamilyMember member3 = new FamilyMember("Sibling","Sibling name3",
                LocalDate.of(1990,12,12),"Male");
        FamilyMember member4 = new FamilyMember("Child","Child name",
                LocalDate.of(2010,12,12),"Male");
        FamilyMember member5 = new FamilyMember("Child","Child name2",
                LocalDate.of(2000,12,12),"Female");
        FamilyMember member6 = new FamilyMember("Spouse","Spouse name",
                LocalDate.of(1990,12,12),"Male");

        List<FamilyMember> listOfFamilyMember = Arrays.asList(member1,member2,
                                              member3,member4,member5,member6);

        Map<String,Long> countMembers = listOfFamilyMember.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(FamilyMember::getMemberType,
               Collectors.counting()));

        System.out.println(countMembers);
    }
}
```

**FamilyMember.java**

```
public class FamilyMember {

    private String memberType;
    private String fullName;
    private LocalDate dateOfBirth;
    private String gender;

    public FamilyMember(String memberType, String fullName, 
                        LocalDate dateOfBirth, String gender) {
        this.memberType = memberType;
        this.fullName = fullName;
        this.dateOfBirth = dateOfBirth;
        this.gender = gender;
    }
    //getters and setters
}
```

**Output:**

```
{Spouse=1, Sibling=3, Child=2}
```